# Measure property on integrals and constant

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$. Assume $f$ is a function such that $d_{X}(f(x),x)\leq C$ for some constant $C$ and for all $x$.
Show that

$\int \int d^2(f(x_2),y_2)d\mu_2(x_2)d\mu_2(y_2) \leq C$.

I tried triangle inequality but cant get to work.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so posting as an answer.)
I don't think the statement is correct, assuming $\mu_2 = \mu$ and $d_X$ is the same as $d$ and a metric in your question. If $f$ is the identity function, then $d(f(x), x) \le 0$ trivially. But if $X = [0,1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure and usual metric, then
$\int \int d^2(f(x_2),y_2)d\mu_2(x_2)d\mu_2(y_2) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x-y)^2 dx dy > 0 = C$.